# Count number of paths of all length in a DAG

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose you have an unweighted **DAG**, and two vertices, **start** `s` and **end**`t`. The problem is to count how many paths there are from `s` to `t` of length *1, 2, 3...N-1*, where `N` is the number of vertices in the DAG.

---

My approach:

- Build a matrix `d` of size `N*N`, where `d[u][k]` is the number of ways to reach `u` from `s` in exactly `k` steps, and set `d[s][0] = 1`
- Find a topological sorting `TS` of the DAG
- Now, for every vertex `u` in `TS`

  - clone the array `d[u]` as `a`
  - shift every element in `a` right by 1 (ie, insert 0 on left, discard rightmost element)
  - for every adjacent vertex `v` of `u`, add array `a` to array `d[v]`
- The answer is `d[t]`

This seems to work in `O(V+EV)`. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient `O(V+E)` way?

Comment: Yes, that sounds just about optimal. As a minor point, you might avoid naming edges *e* in graph problems, as *e* is used for edges, usually. *s* and *t* are more common.

Comment: @AmiTavory Yeah, just realized that! The problem I was trying had limits such that a worst case could only be solved by an `O(V+E)` algorithm. But when I tried it out the test cases allowed `O(VE)`.

Comment: "where d[n][k] is the number of ways to reach n from s in exactly k ways" -- Do you mean "in exactly k *steps*?"  Your current phrasing implies d[n][k] = k.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, I meant a path of length k. Thanks for pointing it out, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal algorithm is *quite likely* `O(VE)`. However a simpler implementation is possible using BFS allowing vertices to be visited multiple times (on most practical cases, this will use less memory than `O(V^2)`.

Comment: It's best not to claim an algorithm is optimal unless you can back the claim up with a lower bound.  (For example: Are you *sure* that using fast matrix multiplication techniques on the adjacency matrix can't be used to give an asymptotically faster algorithm?)